# A cross product on $C^*_{red} G$

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For every group $G$, the reduced group $C^*$-algebra $C^*_{red}G$ is equipped with the inner product $\langle a,b\rangle=tr(ab^*)$ where "$tr$" is the  standard trace on group $C^*$-algebras.

For what kind of groups $G$, $C^*_{red}G$ admit a bounded skew-symmetric  $2$-linear map $\wedge: C^*_{red}G\times C^*_{red}G \to C^*_{red}G$ with the  following  properties:

1) For every $a,b \in C^*_{red}G$, $a\wedge b$ is perpendicular to both $a,b$.

2)For every two independent elements $a,b\in C^*_{red} G$, $a\wedge b$ is a  nonzero element?

Our question is inspired by [the following paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1f6b/ff1e992f60eb87b35c3ceed04272fb5cc298.pdf):

W. S. Massey, Cross Products of Vectors in Higher Dimensional Euclidean Spaces. The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 90, No. 10 (Dec., 1983), pp. 697-701.

Comment: By bounded you mean for the $L^2$ norm given by the trace ? By 2) do you mean linear independance over $\mathbb C$ ? If so, your question boils down to one for Hilbert spaces, and the answer just depends on the cardinal of $G$

Comment: @Bleuderk  By bounded  I  mean for the original  $C^*$ norm.I used the  inner  product  merely  for significance  of perpendicularity, not  any  topological consideration.   By 2), yes  I  mean  $\mathbb{C}$-independent.